# Add ID to each rendered element inside canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I need little help.

How can I add a text inside each rendered element inside canvas ?

here is a fiddle representing my idea:

```js
  

 var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
   var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var x_width = canvas.width;
var y_height = canvas.height;

var dx = 2;
var dy = -2;

var ballRadius = 10;


var data = [
 
   [1,0.506,0.648],
    [2,0.253,0.433],
    [5,0.339,0.445],
    [7,0.396,0.569],
    [8,0.271,0.583],
    [9,0.307,0.187],
    [10,0.431,0.213],
    [12,0.71,1.045],
    [13,0.2,0.259],
    [14,0.272,0.259],
    [15,0.477,0.379]
  
    ];


for (var i = 0; i<=data.length-1; i++) {
    var x = x_width*data[i][1];
    var y = y_height*data[i][2];
    var id = data[i][0];
    drawPlayer (id, x,y);
}

function drawPlayer(id, x, y) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x, y, ballRadius, 0, Math.PI*2);
    ctx.fillStyle = "#0095DD";
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.fillText(id, 0, 0);
    ctx.closePath();
}


drawPlayer();
//setInterval(draw , 100);
```

```css
#myCanvas {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="480" height="320"></canvas>


<div class="play-btn-hld">
  <button class="play">Graj</button>
</div>
```

Can I somehow add a text inside each element ? Idealy the text should be the data[i][0] number. Is it possible ? I can not wrap my head around it.

Or Should I use classic html and css to create similar effect ?

Cheers

Comment: Please fix your snippet, get rid of errors. You want each ball to have number written at top of it?

Comment: I am trying to fix this and yes each ball written number on it.

Comment: @Oen44 errors are fixed, my bad

Comment: Is canvas the best solution for this type of work ?

Comment: Well, using HTML + CSS would do the trick and be even easier to create but... We don't know what do you want to accomplish, how is that (data visualization, game or whatever that is) supposed to work.

Comment: @Oen44 I just want to create an animation to show route for each "ball" based on bigger **data** array.

Answer (score 0):

you need to set the `x` and `y` position of the text to be the same as the circle's position. 
plus measuring the text in order to have it aligned nicely.

here you go:

```
function drawPlayer(id, x, y) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x, y, ballRadius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
  ctx.fillStyle = "#0095DD";
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();

  const textWidth = ctx.measureText(id);
  const textHeight = 12 * 0.5;
  ctx.font = "12px Arial"
  ctx.fillStyle = "#fff";
  ctx.fillText(id, x-textWidth.width/2, y+textHeight/2);
}
```

Comment: You don't need  `ctx.closePath` it is used to create a line from the last point on the path to the previous  `ctx.moveTo` or first point after `ctx.beginPath()` it is not the opposite to `beginPath` and acts like `lineTo` Also you can use ctx.textAlign = "center"; rather than computer the center manualy